# Create publisher from blocking callback

Tags: swift, combine

I have an old callback API, which has a `newValue` callback handler emitting one value at a time, and a `completion` callback, containing an `Error` or nil, if success.

Unfortunately, calling `collecting` blocks until the API sent all values!

```swift
func<T> collecting(newValue: @escaping (T) -> Void, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) { ... }

func publisher<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<T, Error>()
        
    collecting(newValue: { value: T -> Void in
        subject.send(value)
    } completionHandler: { error: Error? -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            subject.send(completion: .failure(error))
        } else {
            subject.send(completion: .finished)
        }
    }
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

This code above does not work, because calling `collecting` blocks, and the return statement is only called with `finished`.

How can you implement such API in Combine?
I don't want to use any `DispatchQueue.async`, because scheduling should be handled by Combine.

Answer (score 0):

wrap `subject.send(value)` with `DispatchQueue.main.async`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    subject.send(value)
}
```

I am not able at this moment to explain why it worked for me.